# form fields; jquery validation

Tags: jquery, validation, text, input

i am trying to validate my form fields calling the input  text ids, but jquery is not validating it. here is what i have:

email2: {// compound rule
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                },

if i change name="email2" it works fine, but i want name="email[]" as i have an array of email that i am getting from user. so then, i gave my input text and id for jquery to validate but it doesnt validate, any ideas?

Comment: This makes no sense as is. Please post more code (preferably all of it) so we have some idea of what is happening, then you may get some helpful answers.

Comment: i think the rules are made to be keyed in as name not id, per the response below. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules are meant to be keyed by name, not id.

Something like this might work for you...

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        "email[]" : { /* compound rule */ }
    }
});
```

Comment: ah, now i know why it didn't work. ok thanks. i will try that.